# Making 2D Motorbike Game Textures

Tags: texture, games

How could I make textures similar to the ground textures in this game: http://www.teagames.com/games/funkytruck3/play.php

Im making something similar but I am totally new to making any game graphics... Even one single "rock" from the ground in the example would probably be enoguh for me because I could rotate it in random directions.

I have photoshop cs5 and gimp.

Comment: Main problem is not drawing 7 different kinds of rocks that go along the border of land, but to have them align with curvy border all they way to the end. I know you cant do this in photoshop. You cud do with programming, but not ideal. Illustrator Or CorelDraw. I think In corel draw its easier. In illustrator you could do but rocks wont be random. Or maybe i dont know? Anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend Photoshop in your case. Just make the rock shape with the pen tool, and if you're not good at digital painting, you could easily use layer styles to make the rock "pop" out a bit like they did in the game.

Edit:
Here's something I quickly scrapped up. Simple pen-tool-made shape. Put a stroke on it, and did the default gradient overlay set to "lighten". This only took about 15 seconds, so, putting a little more effort into it, I'm sure you'll get just what you're looking for.

[image]

How to use the pen tool:
http://www.melissaevans.com/tutorials/how-to-use-photoshops-pen-tool

Comment: 15 seconds?! You're good! :O Even with Illustrator (My tool of choice), it would have taken me quite a while.

Comment: @JFW: Illustrator is my tool of choice as well when it comes to thinks like this. But I don't know, I've second been using photoshop for about 8 years now and it's become second nature to me :]

Comment: @Neb: Glad to hear! Best of luck on your game!